# Injecting An activity into another activity using hilt in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I want to get some functions which are inside an activity into another activiy using hilt
dependency library in kotlin. how do i do that? i did something like below it doesn't work

My Main Activity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    @Inject
    lateinit var mainActivityTwo: MainActivityTwo

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

    }
    fun functionFromMainActivity(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "${mainActivityTwo.functionFromSecondActivity()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

this is my second activity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivityTwo : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainTwoBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainTwoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
    fun functionFromSecondActivity():String{
        return "Function From Second Activity"
    }

}
```

it throws long error like below

[image]

could somebody help me to achieve this?

Comment: Can you put these functions in a shared utility class instead?

Comment: I don't want to use shared utility class. i want to get functions from an activity like i tried above in my code. is there any ways to do?

Comment: It is an impossibility. You cannot instantiate activities outside the Android framework. The instantiated activity will be broken in many ways. This may be an XY problem. It is very strange to say you want to instantiate this kind of class to use its functions externally instead of using utility functions. If it actually has functions that can be used externally like that, they should not be member functions in the first place. There may be something about OOP you misunderstand.

Answer (score 0):

One way to provide binding information to Hilt is constructor injection, like described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#define-bindings).

```
class MainActivityTwo @Inject constructor() : AppCompatActivity()
```

But you really shouldn't inject an instance of `Activity` into another `Activity`, it could have a lot of side effects.

Comment: Above code doesn't work. it throws error.

Comment: What error? @coppersmith

Comment: it throws error like `E:\ForumDiscussion\InjectingMainActivity\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\injectingmainactivity\MainActivityTwo.java:38: error: @Provides methods can only be present within a @Module or @ProducerModule
    public final java.lang.String functionFromSecondActivity() {`

Comment: It says you have `@Provides` annotation in your activity which is not allowed. All you need to do to make a class injectable by hilt is have a single `@Inject constructor` in it. @coppersmith